# Covariant return type with primitive types

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, overloading, covariant-return-types

I have the following:

```
template<typename T>
class AbsContainer {
public:
    virtual T operator[](ptrdiff_t) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class SpecialContainer : public AbsContainer<T>, Box<pair<ptrdiff,T>> {
    class Proxy;
public:
    Proxy operator[](ptrdiff_t i) {
        return Proxy(i, this);
    };
};

template <typename T>
class SpecialContainer<T>::Proxy  {
    ptrdiff_t _i;
    Box* _p;
public:
    Proxy(ptrdiff_t i, Box* p) : _i(i), _p(p);
    Proxy& operator=(const T& elm) {
        _p->::insert(pair<ptrdiff,T>(_i,elm));  //defined in Box
    }
};
```

main:

```
SpecialContainer<int> x;
x[2] = 3;
```

This doesn't compile, because in class `SpecialContainer`, the `operator[]` with the one in `AbsContainer`.

Ideally in concept, `Proxy operator[]` should be an override. So I tried resolving this by achieving covariant return type by making Proxy inherit from T. However it doesn't work since T can be a primitive type, and inheriting from a primitive type has no sense.

Error because of operator conflict :

`error: conflicting return type specified for ‘specialContainer<T>::Proxy B<T>::operator[](std::ptrdiff_t) [with T = int; std::ptrdiff_t = long unsigned int]`

Error because trying to inherit from parametric type T (`int` in this case):

`error: base type ‘int’ fails to be a struct or class type`

Is there any way in which can this be resolved ?

Comment: How does it not compile?  After fixing the order and not using `Proxy` right in `B` it compiles: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bef90d5e7438ca0

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Providing code that actually doesn't demonstrate the problem has very little utility.  I suspect your real problem is over use of `virtual`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I made changes, it is more complete now, excuse my ignorance

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't think the problem is related to virtual,considering I have the same issue with or without it.

Comment: @protoneight Your code remains incomplete.  Please click on [mcve], read it, and then provide one.  I cannot prove you are wrong about `virtual` without actually having code that actually reproduces your actual problem.

Comment: [Example of your code compiling with `virtual` removed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37a311887eb07455), and [not compiling with `virtual` added](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d5e45ca6a1fed9d), after fixing around a dozen errors.  There are still more errors I didn't fix, but enough that clang actually complained about the lack of covariance.  Provide a [mcve] that *actually exhibits the error*, and is both minimal and complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something very similar to covariant types even without any compiler support for actual covariant types. Here's how to do it.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class AbsContainer {
  public:
    T operator[](ptrdiff_t i) { return operator_Abs(i); }
    virtual T operator_Abs(ptrdiff_t) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class SpecialContainer : public AbsContainer<T>, std::map<ptrdiff_t, T>  {
  public:
    class Proxy;
    Proxy operator[](ptrdiff_t i) { return operator_Spec(i); }
    T operator_Abs(ptrdiff_t i) override {
        return operator_Spec(i).get();
    }
    virtual Proxy operator_Spec(ptrdiff_t i) {
        return Proxy(i, this);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class SpecialContainer<T>::Proxy  {
    ptrdiff_t _i;
    std::map<ptrdiff_t, T>* _p;
public:
    Proxy(ptrdiff_t i, std::map<ptrdiff_t, T>* p) : _i(i), _p(p) {};
    Proxy& operator=(const T& elm) {
        _p->insert(std::pair<ptrdiff_t,T>(_i,elm));
        return *this;
    }
    T get() { return (*_p)[_i]; }
};

int main()
{
       SpecialContainer<std::string> spec;
       AbsContainer<std::string>& abs = spec;
       auto k = spec[42];
       k = "Hello World";
       std::cout << abs[42] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The entire _reason_ to have the `Proxy` class is to support the `Proxy& operator=(const T& elm)` that does more than simply assign the value. And your code is fundamentally incompatible with this.

Comment: @MooingDuck Edited the answer, added requested functionality. Please point out what else is incompatible.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88f60013062a4b0b container[0] = 3; // error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.  Note that `std::vector<bool>` returns a proxy that allows you to assign directly to it, but that had to sacrifice the interface slightly because it couldn't be covariant.

Comment: @MooingDuck Of course you cannot assign to a B through an A; A's interface doesn't allow assigning.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: This isn't about A's interface, this is about T's interface. And since `A::operator[]` returns a `T`, that means B can't instead return a Proxy that allows conversion to/from T, like std::vector<bool> does, which is exactly what the OP is trying to do in `Proxy& operator=(const T& elm)`

Comment: @n.m. Very cool thank you ! This answers my question. I made some adjustments to Proxy so it converts automatically to T. However, I don't understand the use of operator_impl_A, since the behavior seems to be the same if I delete it in both classes.

Comment: @MooingDuck It doesn't look like we're on the same page. Why do you think `container[0] = 3` is supposed to ever work? I was not tasked to implement this. `operator[]` in the parent class is specified to return `T`, not `T&`.

Comment: @protoneight I changed the code to reflect your example more closely. It compiles and runs. I replaced `Box` with `std::map` just to use something specific.

Comment: @MooingDuck "This isn't about A's interface, this is about T's interface." I don't think you are thinking about the same set of requirements OP is thinking about.

Comment: @protoneight Can you show me what exactly was removed and how the modified code looks like? You cannot just remove `operator_impl_A` because `A::operator[]` calls it.

Comment: @n.m. sorry I meant op_impl_B. (op_Spec)
This is a test code : https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0b2b93b96f2d821

Comment: @n.m.: I disagree. The OP clearly is merely lacking the vocabulary to describe their problem, which can be seen in the code: `specialContainer<T>` should return a `Proxy`, that allows `SpecialContainer<int> x; x[2] = 3;`, but they can't make this work with a generic `AbsContainer` interface, which doesn't support the use of the proxy.

Comment: @MooingDuck When you return a covariant type in a subclass, you do *not* mean that the base class has access to the extension.  Rather, when you know you are the subclass, you get the subclass enhanced behavior; when you are the base, you get the base class behavior.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Yes. And that's exactly what this answer _ought_ to say. What the OP wants cannot be done. The two concepts are fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: @moo that is exactly what this answer does.  I explained this answer.  I have no idea what you think this answer says.  The OP's example also doesn't show assigning through index of base, so I have no idea why you think the OP wants that.

Comment: @protoneight I see! It is needed e.g. for the case one wants to derive a further subclass from SpecialContainer, override `operator[]` further, and make the return type covariant again. In general it is often a goof idea to make all public methods non-virtual, and make them forward calls to private virtual method. See e.g. [this FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance). But you can skip this and it will also work.

Comment: @MooingDuck What OP wants is very clearly written in the text of the question. I don't detect any lack of vocabulary here. I think understand the problem completely because I have encountered very similar problems in the past and I have invented this here method to solve them. OP agrees that this method solves their problem. If you think otherwise, please feel free to post your own answer and explain that it cannot be done.